# Copy two different datagridview to be one datagridview

Tags: vb.net

My initial code:

```
Private Sub Transfer_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView6.CellContentClick

    Dim i As Integer
    vTableTransfer = New DataTable
    vTableTransfer.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    vTableTransfer.Columns.Add("Type", GetType(String))
    vTableTransfer.Columns.Add("Len", GetType(Double))
    vTableTransfer.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Double))
    vTableTransfer.Columns.Add("OD", GetType(Double))

   Try
    For i = 0 To DataGridView6.Rows.Count - 3
        If DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells("Transfer").Value = True Then
            vRow = vTableTransfer.NewRow
            vRow.Item(0) = DataGridView13.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            vRow.Item(1) = DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells("Type").Value
            vRow.Item(2) = DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells("Len").Value
            vRow.Item(3) = DataGridView13.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
            If IsDBNull(vRow.Item(3)) Then DataGridView13.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = 0
            If DataGridView13.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = 0 Then DataGridView13.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value=DataGridView5.Columns.Item(1)
            vRow.Item(4) = DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells("OD").Value
            If IsDBNull(vTableTransfer.Rows) Then Exit Sub
            vTableTransfer.Rows.Add(vRow)
        End If
    Next
    DataGridView12.DataSource = vTableTransfer


 Catch ex As Exception 
 End Try 
End sub
```

I have three datagridview( dgv6 & dgv13 & dgv5) where dgv13 is copy from dgv5 then copy the data to be one datagridview (dgv12) by using checkbox column in dgv6, there are 12 row data on dgv6 and 6 row in dgv13,  the program was running well after data on dgv13 empty ( count step -7) then the program was stop catch by DBnull exception. my attemp to are to keep fill data on dgv12 instead event no row data in dgv13 which cacth dbnull where they stop then copy previous cell from dgv13 to finish transfering data to dgv12.

I have trial to cacth dbnull and put put some code to do keep filling data on dgv12 but seem like doesn't work, is it possible todo that or any other methode please advise...many Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think i found some tricky, that working fine to avoid catch by dbnull, just continue write some value on dgv13 while checkbutton_click checked on dgv6 so dgv13 continue add value on row instead add value on dgv12.

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView6.Rows.Count - 3
            If DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells("Transfer").Value = True Then
                vRow = vTableLink.NewRow
                vRow.Item(0) = ("OH").ToString
                vRow.Item(1) = ("0").ToString
                vRow.Item(2) = ("0").ToString
                If IsDBNull(vTableLink.Rows) Then Exit Sub
                vTableLink.Rows.Add(vRow)
            End If
```